# Add a separator to edit rejection message boxes that contain multiple rejection reasons

Tags: feature-request, edits

I attempted to edit [jquery ui tabs problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745797/jquery-ui-tabs-problem) and got this message box:

---

[image: screenshot of notification box]

---

*(Until now I wasn't aware you could get more than one of these at once. Is this relevant to all sites or just Stack Overflow?)*

I've seen each message separately enough times to figure out that it's actually two messages rolled into one:

> please do not use these words in titles: 'problem'

and

> a question with that title already exists; please be more specific.

But for the sake of clarity to users who aren't as familiar, shouldn't there be some sort of separator between the messages? Currently it's a run-on sentence, which is at best annoying and at worst unclear.

Alternately, the messages could come one at a time, though I think that has the potential to be frustrating depending on the order in which the messages appear— I think the user would want to know about the "problem" restriction first, lest they reword the title to be unique and yet still contain "problem".

Comment: The lack of capitalization makes the splice even worse. Definitely needs fixing.

Comment: This is all avoiding the larger issue: you attempted to submit your edit without fixing that awful title. Shame, shame, shame!

Comment: @Pop I'm just going through and fixing potential formatting issues detected by [this query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/q/119551/posts-with-possible-code-formatting-issues). Trying not to get too bogged down with other problems in posts, but I did eventually replace "problem" with "issue", as is my standard procedure when I get that message box. "Fixed" :)

Comment: Nice query! I got through all of two posts before I started hitting stuff you'd already edited.

Comment: @Pop Yeah, it's a useful query. I just wish Data Explorer were fed more often. I started at the beginning; I'm nearly done with everything it's found up to 2009 now. You could look at 2010 or later for stuff I haven't gotten to yet.

Comment: Ah, I didn't look closely enough to see the date flag originally. I'm going to reach Copy Editor on the back of this query.

Comment: @Pop Err, and by 2009 I meant 2010. But you probably figured that out when you saw that line of the query.